# Why can't I reassign an object when passing that object as a parameter to a handler function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, parameters, destroy

I have an object with a method, destroy:

```
let object = {
    destroy() {
        handleDestroy.call(null, this);
    }
}

function handleDestroy(obj) {
    obj = null;
}
```

I know that technically the object is not destroyed even if it did work, but I am wondering why I can't reassign objects to null or other types of objects this way? When I call handleDestroy with the object as a parameter, or if I invoke the destroy method, object remains unchanged.

Comment: You’re just reassigning the parameter. It’s like reassigning a variable—it doesn’t change the value.

Comment: Parameters are passed by value, not by reference. Assigning to `obj` just assigns to the local variable, not the caller's variable. Also, it's not possible to assign anything to `this`, it's not a real variable.

Comment: Looks like I need to do some more reading on this. Thanks everyone